# Java generics: Declare map value of generic type

Tags: java, generics, casting

I am new to generics.

Having a `Map` like

```
private static Map<String, Object> map;
```

and a method like

```
public <T> T getObject(final Class<T> myClass) {
    return (T)map.get(myClass);
}
```

How to change the map declaration in order to not have to do the cast when returning from the method ?

Comment: Is there a chance for you to declare the map like `Map<String, Class<T>>`?

Comment: @nobeh The IDE is saying: T cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: I think @Pablo has a nice answer to this.

Comment: why do you have a non-static member function for a static field?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would need to make a generic class, not a generic method:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
   private Map<String, T> map;

   public T getObject(final String key) {
    return map.get(key);
   }
}
```

Also, I changed the parameter from a Class to a String. It doesn't make sense to pass a Class if map.get() expects a String.

Edit: I didn't notice that map was static. If you can change it to non-static without it breaking other parts of your program, this could work. If you can't, then you cannot avoid a cast.

Comment: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type T

Comment: @DisplayName OK, map is static, I missed that. Then if you cannot change map from static to non-static, this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid the cast operation as the get() method returns Object
see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) for more info

Comment: Unless you can somehow declare the Map as being of type Map<String,T>, which doesn't seem to fit your example

Comment: @Miquel even so it wouldn't change the problem, the method get() returns an object, not an instance of T

Comment: @Miquel I tried that, but does not work. Could you please tell me why ?

Comment: @DisplayName it depends on how you did it. Maybe you can post the code?  For one thing, the Map would have to be declared inside your class (the one that has the getObject) or you'll have two unrelated T's with different values.

Comment: Oh, there look at @Pablo that's how

Comment: @Grimmy `Map.get()` returns an object of type `V`, i.e. the generic type of its values (unsurprisingly) - [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)).  You might be thinking of the fact that the *parameter* to get is always an `Object` rather than a `K`?

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle yes, I see the difference. Apparently the method signature changed over the Java releases and I didn't noticed so far. For example in 1.4, it used to return Object, hence my mistake

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to drop the `static` modifier of your map, than you can do like so:

```
public class MyClass<T> {

    private Map<String, T> map;

    public T getObject(final Class<T> myClass) {
        return map.get(myClass);
    }
}
```

Otherwise:

> It is a compile-time error to refer to a type parameter of a generic
>   class C anywhere in:
>
> - the declaration of a static member of C

(excerpt from the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2)), which prevents you from using parameterized class to achieve the above.

What *you* were trying to do, however, is to refer a parameterized **method**'s type-parameter from another member (which happen to also be static), which also unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

my working generic java map

```java
public class JsonUtils {
    /** gson with disable html escaping */
    public static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();

    public static <K, V> String toJson(Map<K, V> dataMap) {
        return gson.toJson(dataMap);
    }
}
```

usage

```java
java.util.Map<String, Object> dataMap = new java.util.HashMap<>();
dataMap.put("paymentchannel", "BALANCE");
dataMap.put("shortcode", "");
dataMap.put("transtype", "cvm");
System.out.println(JsonUtils.toJson(dataMap));
```