# Java: make one of the Map<> variable generic

Tags: java, generics

I need to store variable and value as a pair somewhere and I tend to use Map. The problem is the type of value would be different so I think generic should be used. So I tried something like this:

```
Map<String, T> netPara;
```

and of course it does not work, then I tried

```
Map<String, Object> netPara;
```

This worked but when I retrived value it returned only of type Object, instead of "boolean", "int".

Can anyone help me out? I believe it tends to be simple but I am not an expert, yet. Thanks in advance.

In fact I have a function A who receives a list of parameters, but then it's function B who will also use these parameters but B's parameters list is vide, so I hope to store them as a class parameter and reused by function B. So here is what I did:

```
Class Person() {
Map<String, T> infoPaire; // if I use Object to replace T
Function A: receiver(boolean b, int i, String1 st1, String2 st2) {
    infoPaire.put("b", b);
    infoPaire.put("i", i);
    infoPaire.put("st1", st1);
    infoPaire.put("st2", st2);
}

Function B: user() {
    boolean b = infoPaire.get("b"); // I need to add (boolean) to cast and I dont want it, it's ugly
    int i = infoPaire.get("i");
    String st1 = infoPaire.get("st1");
    String st2 = infoPaire.get("st2");
}
```

Comment: share some piece of code. how are you doing it? Is it a local or instance variable?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012989/java-generics-declare-map-value-of-generic-type

Comment: Maybe this helps:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416540/java-map-with-values-limited-by-keys-type-parameter

Comment: You need to go back to your design stage. What are you trying to accomplish with a mapping of a string to some object?  What will you be doing with the retrieved object? How does the mapped item work with your Class model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see now that you are asking a slightly different question than I had originally thought. I will leave my other answer up though, since it explains why this is a problem.

Since you are only dealing with `Strings`, `Booleans`, and `Integers` you could do what you are asking by only storing `Strings` in your `Map` and converting to the proper type later.

```
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put("bool", "true");
m.put("int", "1");

Integer i = Integer(m.get("int"));
Boolean b = Boolean(m.get("bool"));
```

This would be pseudo *safe*, but you would have to track the types for the values somewhere else in your code.

Probably the best solution would be to use three `Maps`, one for each type.

```
Map<String, String> stringMap;
Map<String, Integer> intMap;
Map<String, Boolean> boolMap;
```

There is really no harm in having three maps, in general.

For reasons why you can't use one map cleanly, see my other answer on this question.

Comment: I finally choose to use multi-map to solve the problem. it seems to be easy. thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 3):

`T` needs to be defined as a generic parameter on either the class or the method.

## Method

```
public <T> Map<String, T> getMap(){
    return new HashMap<String, T>();
}
```

## Class

```
public class Test <T> {

    public Map<String, T> getMap(){
        return new HashMap<String, T>();
     }
}
```

## Usage

### Method

When using the method

```
Test t = new Test();
Map<String, Double> m = t.<Double>getMap();
```

or more concisely,

```
Map<String, Double> m = t.getMap();
```

Since the `Double` can be inferred from the right hand side.

### Class

With a class.

```
Test<String> t = new Test<String>;
```

or with type inference,

```
Test<String> t = new Test<>;
```

And

```
Map<String, Integer> m = t.getMap()
```

And all together,

```
Test<String> t = new Test<>;
Map<String, String> m = t.getMap();
Test<Integer> t2 = new Test<>;
Map<String, Integer> m2 = t2.getMap();
```

## Warning

For the type inference stuff, i.e. `<>` and `t.getMap()` with no type parameter, you must be using Java 7 or greater.

## Other Warning About the Type System in General

Using generics allows you to create code that manipulates values without knowing what they are, but there are some caveats. With reference to your question, it sounds like you *might* be trying to store two values of different type in the `Map`, like so,

```
m.put('int', 7)
m.put('bool', true)
```

**This would not be possible**. Because `T`, while generic, must eventually resolve to a single type for instance of the class. For instance,

```
Map<String, Integer> m;
```

This map could **only** ever hold **`Integer`** values.

The reason that declaring `Object` as the value works is because *every* class in Java is a subclass of `Object`, so anything can go in there. **But using `Object` is very bad design.** You are essentially *turning off* the type system, which is one of the major advantages that a language like Java brings to the table, static typing.

So, if you find yourself wanting to store a collection of homogeneous values, you might want to reconsider your design. Even in languages which explicitly allow such things (scheme, python, JavaScript, etc.) it is usually a sign of a design flaw to use them in a homogeneous manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can make one of the types a type parameter, but then you must also declare it as a type parameter. Just giving it a one-letter name such as `T` does not automatically make it a type parameter.

```
class MyClass<T> {   // Note: T is a type parameter
    private Map<String, T> netPara;

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best you can hope for is a type of Object for value and a typed getter method that has an unsafe cast:

```
class VariableMap extends HashMap<String, Object> {
   public <T> T getValue(Object key) {
       return (T)super.get(key);
   }
{
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand [generic](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm) and [type-casting](http://www.studytonight.com/java/type-casting-in-java.php) first. 
As far as your question is concerned, Object Class stood on top level in inheritance, means Object is the parent class of All java classes.

So you can cast any object in into Object class with out casting, but when you need to get you object back in its actual class you have to cast it. like `String str = (String) netPara.get(key);`

you need to look into polymorphism, casting, and generic concepts. Generic come to solve the problem you are facing right now.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the way to put elements into the map check it once

```
 public class TakingInput {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<String,Object>();

Integer in=new Integer(123);

Object obj=in;

String s=new String("suresh");

Object obj2=s;

map.put("hi",obj);

map.put("ramesh",obj2);

System.out.println(map);

  //to retrive 

 String ss=(String) map.get("ramesh"); //type casting

System.out.println(ss); //o/p:suresh


}

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like

```
BigDecimal n = dictionary.get("n");
String s = dictionary.get("s");
```

which could have

```
class Dictionary {
    public <T> T get(String name) { ... }
```

Because of the type erasure (the compiled/run-time code no longer knowing the generic types), you **cannot do this**,  cast the object to return as T.

The solution:

```
BigDecimal n = dictionary.get(BigDecimal.class, "n");
String s = dictionary.get(String.class, "s");
```

which could be implemented with run-time cast exceptions:

```
public class Dictionary {
    private Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

    public <S> S put(Class<S> type, String name, S value) {
        Object oldValue = map.put(name, value);
        return type.cast(oldValue);
    }

    public <T> T get(Class<T> type, String name) {
        Object value = map.get(name);
        return type.cast(value);
    }
}
```

One could store the type itself, maybe as additional key, a `Map<Class<?>, Map<String, Object>>>`, but one still would not have gained much in this too open problem context.